# Those groups where the inverse function is a composable term function

Tags: group-theory, logic

Consider the class of groups, in the signature of a single binary operation $\{+\}$ (which may of course be multiplication, but I am just using $+$ as the binary operation symbol). In general, the unary inverse function $-x$ is not always composable from the $+$ operation. But for certain individual groups, it is, like every group where for every element $x$ in the group, $n*x = 0$, for some fixed positive integer $n$. I predict that those are the only cases. To make the question precise, suppose $G$ is a particular group, where the inverse function is composable from $+$. Must it be the case that $G$ is of that form?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by composable... But if it's something like "the function $x \mapsto -x$ can be written as $x \mapsto \Phi(x)$ where $\Phi$ is an expression containing only $x$ and $+$", then yes, since the only such well-defined $\Phi$ are of the form $n \times x$, where $n$ is one more than the number of times $+$ appeared. So in that case the function $x \mapsto x + \Phi(x)$ is identically $0$, ie the group has exponent dividing $n + 1$. But if you meant "for all $x$, $-x$ can be written as some combination of $x$s and $+$s", then no. An example is $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I mean the former. If you provide a proof of your assertion as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The following turns Izaak van Dongen's comment into an answer to move this question off the unanswered queue; if he adds an answer of his own I'll delete this one, and in the meantime I've made this CW to avoid reputation gain.*

The key point is **associativity**: since $+$ is associative in any group, we can by induction show that every $\{+\}$-term in the single variable $x$ is equivalent (in the context of groups) to one of the form $$(...((x+x)+x) ... +x) \quad\mbox{($n$ times)},$$ that is, to $nx$ for some $n$. In fact, this means the result holds more generally in all **power associative** inverse magmas.

So if the map $x\mapsto -x$ can be expressed as a term in $+$ alone, it must be of the form $nx$. And for each $n$ this definition works exactly when every element of the group has order dividing $n+1$.